# How to get screen size on css3?

Tags: html, css, screen

I'm trying to see if your screen is a specific amount of pixels so if it's smaller that for example 1000px
this will happen:

```
max-width:750;
```

This is the pixels on the web browser like google chrome and also will get bigger when you zoom out on google chrome if possible.
Thank you.

Comment: screen or viewport width?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean there but like, google chrome width

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you're looking for can be done with CSS3 [media queries](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-mediaqueries/). They're a way to execute CSS only under certain conditions. Here's the [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Media_queries) article, too.

Your media query might look like this:

```
@media (max-device-width : 1000px) {
    /* CSS */
}
```

Comment: Is the mign-device-width the google chrome or the screen, just wondering. But should be fine.

Comment: See the answer by @Clayton. I really should have included that in my answer.

Comment: This is not working. Does this matter when I'm using a seperate css file?

Comment: Hi, I'm looking back at this question years later. I made no sense then but it looks like your answer was what I was looking for, so I will accept it. Thank you for the help!

Answer (score 1):

max-width is the width of the target display area, ex:Google Chrome

max-device-width is the width of the device's entire rendering area, ex:the mobile device screen

Comment: Should this work then?
    #main{
     max-width: max-width/4*3;